# Did the Ottoman government inherit every person's property when they died?

Tags: ottoman-empire, inheritance

Here is a link to a [worldbuilding SE question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/246265/will-this-idea-reduce-corruption):

It asks about a system where the government, and not someone's family, inherits their property when they die, and whether that system would reduce corruption.

And I remembered reading that there was allegedly such a system in the Ottoman Empire.

So did such a system exist in the Ottoman Empire?  And if it did, how did it affect the level of corruption in the Ottoman Empire?

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: Couldn't find anything on a super quick search, but such a thing would have made perfect sense for the [Janissaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janissary), as they were (initially) prohibited from having any family of their own, and were officially slaves of the Sultan.